# Java Swing repack components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have problem with pack function, when using Card Layout. 
I created 1 JFrame which include JPanel(in cardlayout) and this JPanel contains two JPanels.
... so when I run my program the windows is resized to biggest JPanel in program and i cant dynamicly resize it.

now screens:
my background1(smaller background) class when i run program only with this panel has width like 200
http://i41.tinypic.com/scfi88.jpg
when i run my program with added background2 the background gets width of it so it looks for like 400
http://i41.tinypic.com/2lu742x.jpg
so it gets width of my background2 panel

In both backgrounds classes i have buttons to return to preview background, but it never resize. I lready used revalidate and repaint functions on thoose action buttons.
code:
main class and
background1 and
background2(background codes are big because they are generated by netbeans design mode(they are just few empty components):

```
public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private JPanel mainPanel;

public main() {
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    add(mainPanel);

    Background2 card1 = new Background2(mainPanel);
    Background1 card2 = new Background1(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.add(card1,"card1");
    mainPanel.add(card2,"card2");
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout());
    cl.show(mainPanel, "card1");
    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}



public class Background1 extends javax.swing.JPanel {


private JPanel mainPanel;
/**
 * Creates new form HomePanel
 */
public Background1(JPanel panel) {
    mainPanel=panel;
    initComponents();
}


public JPanel getMainPanel() {
    return mainPanel;
}

public void setMainPanel(JPanel mainPanel) {
    this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    left_Panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    zakladka1_Button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    background_Panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    powrot_Button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable3 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    zakladka1_Button.setText("button");
    zakladka1_Button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            zakladka1_ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout left_PanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(left_Panel);
    left_Panel.setLayout(left_PanelLayout);
    left_PanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        left_PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(left_PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(zakladka1_Button)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    left_PanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        left_PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(left_PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(5, 5, 5)
            .addComponent(zakladka1_Button)
            .addGap(433, 433, 433))
    );

    jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout background_PanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(background_Panel);
    background_Panel.setLayout(background_PanelLayout);
    background_PanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        background_PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(background_PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 452, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(83, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    background_PanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        background_PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, background_PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 319, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    powrot_Button.setText("<--");
    powrot_Button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            powrot_ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    jTable3.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTable3);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(left_Panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                    .addComponent(powrot_Button)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(background_Panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(powrot_Button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(left_Panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(background_Panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(115, 115, 115))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42))))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void powrot_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout());
    cl.show(mainPanel, "card1");
    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
}                                             

private void zakladka1_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

}                                                



// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel background_Panel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable3;
private javax.swing.JPanel left_Panel;
private javax.swing.JButton powrot_Button;
private javax.swing.JButton zakladka1_Button;
// End of variables declaration                   
}

public class Background2 extends javax.swing.JPanel {


private JPanel mainPanel;

public Background2(JPanel panel) {
    mainPanel=panel;
    initComponents();  
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    loginFieldLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    zalogujButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    loginField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    passwordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    logowanieLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    passwordFieldLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    loginFieldLabel.setText("Login");

    zalogujButton.setText("Zaloguj");
    zalogujButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            zalogujButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    loginField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            loginFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    passwordField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            passwordFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    logowanieLabel.setText("Logowanie");

    passwordFieldLabel.setText("Hasło");

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(zalogujButton)
            .add(149, 149, 149))
        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(logowanieLabel)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(56, 56, 56)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                .add(passwordFieldLabel)
                                .add(loginFieldLabel))
                            .add(26, 26, 26)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                                .add(loginField)
                                .add(passwordField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 193, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(105, 105, 105)
                    .add(jButton1)))
            .addContainerGap(190, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .add(logowanieLabel)
            .add(29, 29, 29)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(loginField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(loginFieldLabel))
            .add(28, 28, 28)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(passwordFieldLabel)
                .add(passwordField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .add(33, 33, 33)
            .add(zalogujButton)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
            .add(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(101, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void zalogujButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

}                                             

private void loginFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void passwordFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout());
    cl.show(mainPanel, "card2");
    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
}                                        



// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField loginField;
private javax.swing.JLabel loginFieldLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel logowanieLabel;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField;
private javax.swing.JLabel passwordFieldLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton zalogujButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Edit:

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout());
cl.show(mainPanel, "card1");
l.preferredLayoutSize(mainPanel);//l = ShowingSizeCardLayout i added here prints on dim.width and dim.height 
mainPanel.revalidate();
```

output:

```
width: 509
height: 323
width: 1203
height: 537
```

but it is always 509 323.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (One source file, not 3.)  BTW - PNG is better than JPG for screenshots..  See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: OK, i fixed a little bit code. About the pics i dont have enough reputation to use that feature. Thx for advices.

Comment: *"About the pics i dont have enough reputation to use that feature"*  The link I gave has almost nothing to do with posting images to the site and *everything* to do with *making* great images that can be uploaded to this site, any other image site, or used to document the program itself.  Please read it again, more carefully this time.  As to uploading images onto *this* site (SO), if they were not JPEG they'd be smaller in bytes, and I'd have done that for you.

Comment: BTW - taking out the space between the sources and making the entire post 'one text area' is not what I meant.  If you copy/paste that mess it won't compile (try it if you don't believe me).  An SSCCE of a run-time problem should compile for everyone.  Please, read the document carefully..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of CardLayout is to set
the container's preferred size as the
component that is showing size plus insets.

You should subclass CardLayout and override
`preferredLayoutSize` method:

```
class ShowingSizeCardLayout extends CardLayout {

    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container container) {

        Insets insets = container.getInsets();

        Dimension dim = null;

        for (Component component : container.getComponents()) {
            if (component.isVisible()) {
                dim = component.getPreferredSize();
            }
        }

        dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
        dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;

        return dim;

    }
}
```

This will do, but add code to check for null pointers.

Comment: Hmm almost. When i run program the panel is resized to smaller JPanel. And when i change to 2nd bigger panel gets smaller width size. SO before instead 200 was 400, now instead 400 200. I started to call this prefferedsizefuncion when changing card, and it seems that it calculate good width and height but the jpanel is not resized(CODE in first post after "EDIT")

Comment: You should not call `preferredLayoutSize`. It is supposed to the layout manager do this. The frame, and as a consequence, the panel with card layout will have the size of the first "panel card". If you change the showing card, the frame and the main panel are not supposed to be resized automatically, even if the preferred size changed. In `preferredLayoutSize` you are setting the preferred size, not the current size. If you want to resize the frame to its preferred size, call `pack` method. Again, do not call `preferredLayoutSize`.

Comment: Great success!! Thx a lot both. Using overwritten CardLayout with fram.pack() solved my problems!!

@Andrew Thompson problem solved so i won't edit the first post, sorry ;p

Comment: ach one more q. Whats if i for example dynamicly create table and add there 10 rows? I should in same way call preferreflayoutsize method and then pack or so ?

Comment: You should not call `preferredLayoutSize`. The layout manager will do this when you call `pack`.

Comment: Then i am stack again heh When i use JPanel(with overwritten cardlayout) everything works fine. But when i add to this panel next JPanel with overwritten cardlayout, Frame not include changing width/height of this 2nd panel.

Comment: You need to call `pack` on the frame. But I think it's not a good idea resizing a window.

Comment: What do u mean? You mean that i should at beginign set size of app frame to for example 800x600 ?

Comment: When your code changed the card of the card layout, if you want it to be resized to the size of the panel that is visible, call `pack` on the frame.

Comment: Yes i am calling pack. When i use only one Jpanel (cardlayout), pack fix everything. When i added second Jpanel with cardlayout in to it, it isnt resizing correctly.

Comment: Add a SSCCE. I can't understand your problem.